# Dictionary TKey Indexer Using String

Tags: c#, dictionary, indexer

I have an `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` where the `TKey` is a class. Can I add the ability to use the Indexer with a `String` value instead of a `TKey`?

```
public class MyClass {
  public string Name { get; set; }
}

....

//dict is a IDictionary<MyClass, object> 
dict.Add(new MyClass { Name = "Foo" });
```

Currently I'm using Linq to access the values by `Name` but I would prefer something like this:

```
//This call returns the variable I added above
object value = dict["Foo"];
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You could implement `IDictionary<,>` in your own class.. ?

Comment: @Simon I was trying to avoid creating my own `IDictionary`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a good approach to your problem, if using the `Name` to define equality makes 
sense for `MyClass` generally, and not just in this particular dictionary:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Name.GetHashCode();
    }
    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        return this.Name == ((MyClass)other).Name;
    }
}
```

Then your dictionary is simply indexed by `MyClass` objects.  If you have an explicit `string` instead of a `MyClass` instance, you can get the dictionary's value like this:

```
dict[new MyClass { Name = "Foo" }]
```

You could also add a:

```
public static implicit operator MyClass(string s)
{
    return new MyClass { Name = s };
}
```

And index like:

```
dict["Foo"]
```

Again, only do this if it makes sense for `MyClass` generally, not just for use in this particular dictionary.  If it's for this particular dictionary, try another solution.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I didn't think about using an implicit operator, and the end result is exactly what I needed.

Comment: @SimonHartcher do you think it's a good approach to create an (useless) instanse of `MyClass` each time you need to access the one stored in the dictionary?

Comment: @KonstantinVasilcov In my case, I do. I don't have to create an `IDictionary` just for this specific problem, and the code impact is minimal. Unless I'm missing something, I don't see a big issue with it.

Answer (score 3):

You could create your own dictionary class based on your class.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // You may want to implement equality members on your class so that 
    // the dictionary treats the Name value as the key correctly.
}

public class MyClassDictionary<TValue> : Dictionary<MyClass, TValue>
{
    public TValue this[string val]
    {
        get
        {
            return base[Keys.First(x => x.Name == val)];
        }
    }
}
```

You can then use this as you wanted to.

```
MyClassDictionary<string> instance = new MyClassDictionary<string>();

instance.Add(new MyClass() { Name = "testkey" }, "test value");

Debug.WriteLine(instance["testkey"]);
```

Comment: I went with Tim's answer as I only needed to change MyClass with his solution. This solution does work however :)

Comment: No worries, implicit operator also eluded me as a simple answer :>